# Handle activity using Activity Life Cycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In my app i am launching **LoginActivity.java** just after **SplashScreenActivity.java**, but whenever i am starting my app again after closing it properly, not starting from exact activity **LoginActivity.java** (whereas it has to be)

I am playing with small case - **case says:** if ***txtEvent and txtOperative equals to null*** launch **LicenseListActivity.java** else **current activity (LoginActivity.java).**

But everytime its calling **LicenseListActivity.java** whereas my txtEvent and txtOperative is not null, i checked by using Log.

```
where i am doing mistake ? which method i need to use to make my case successfull?
```

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
 private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

                txtDeviceID.setText(deviceID);
             txtEmailID.setText(emailID);

             prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

             txtEvent.setText(prefs.getString("autoSaveEvent", event));
             Log.d("txtEvent::onCreate::", txtEvent.getText().toString());           


             txtOperative.setText(prefs.getString("autoSaveOperative", operative));
             Log.d("txtOperative::onCreate::", txtOperative.getText().toString());  

 txtEvent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                  @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                            int count)
                  {

                  }

                  @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                int after)
                  {

                  }

                  @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                  {
                    prefs.edit().putString("autoSaveEvent", s.toString()).commit();
                  }
                });

             txtOperative.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                  @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                            int count)
                  {

                  }

                  @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                int after)
                  {

                  }

                  @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                  {
                    prefs.edit().putString("autoSaveOperative", s.toString()).commit();
                  }
                });

             strEvent = txtEvent.getText().toString();
             strOperative = txtOperative.getText().toString();

             if  (txtEvent.getText().toString().equals("") && txtOperative.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Intent intentCall = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LicenseListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentCall);
                }
             else 
                {
                // show current activity
                }


}

    @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

      }

      @Override
      protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

      }

      @Override
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

      }

      @Override
      protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

      }
     }
```

Comment: Do U get anything in log of txtEvent & txtOperative ?

Comment: @SagarShah yes i am getting correct values